# Child div 100% height to parent auto height

Tags: html, css

Im here because other similar questions couldn't help my particular problem.

I need `right div` to be 100% height all the time, where the `parent` height depends on `left div` height which depends on content inside.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

​Here is CSS:

```
.container{
    min-height: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.left{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.right{   
    min-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.

.clearfix:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

​Note:
I'm using `clearfix`.
And if you can show your answer in `jsfiddle`

Here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C9Kmx/32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your comments on other solutions it is clear to me that only solution for you is to implement some JS into your code. This is not a problem, however.

http://jsfiddle.net/b7TuP/

Comment: as for now, I see only one solution and it's including js, so basically it's impossible to do it with plain css.

Answer (score 15):

Make the right div `position:absolute;` and make the parent div `position:relative;` and then `height:100%;` will work for the right div. Make sure you also adjust its x-position and width accordingly. In this example I gave it a `left:50px` to make sure it appears to the right of the left column.

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/e9mvD/

Comment: I cant give it left: 50px because the with will be relative

Comment: In that case, you can set a fixed width on the container div and then use `right:0` on the absolutely-positioned right div, and just give that right div a width as well.

Comment: This solution worked best for me. Prefer this over having to include javascript

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this using flexbox and some creativity.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px
}

.left {
  height: 200px;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would agree, but because IE11 is still supported it has some serious inconsistencies with how Chrome and Firefox are implementing flexbox. Point being flexbox has its limitations until IE11 is dropped.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `table-cell` value of the `display` property in this layout and remove the `float` like this:

```
.left, .right{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/C9Kmx/34/

Comment: +1 This is imo the best solution as it does not impose any other restrictions on the left and right elements..

Comment: This property uses lowest height , basically if I use 100% height no `right` div it just collapses.

Answer (score 1):

Give `position:fixed` and `height:100%` for the right div. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Can you show me a jsfiddle, because I can't understand why isn't it working for me

Comment: You can see its leaping over parrent div. It's not what I want. I want it to be inside.

Comment: Replace position:fixed with position:absolute, and set position: relative on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
.child{
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.child_absolute{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child_absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try by giving the height of container a fixed value

this will also fix the issue. Just tried it in jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/C9Kmx/35/

```
.container
{
    min-height: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: As stated, It can not be fixed