# Textarea height 100% in a DIV height in percentage

Tags: css, textarea

I can find how to get a 100% Textarea in a DIV width fixed height, but nothing for fluid contents.

Here what I'm looking for:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:1px;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F60;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #069;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.content textarea{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
 
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -75px;
    clear:both;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="container">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="content">message<br />
   <textarea>This textarea doesn't fill the content in height.</textarea>
      
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Basically, I need to fill the content with textarea.

Is that possible?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Child div 100% height to parent auto height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409586/child-div-100-height-to-parent-auto-height)

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is relative which means it depends on a parent value. If you don't have a value it can reference it won't work very well, let's say the wrapper has a height: 100px then it's very explicit that 100% is 100px #cheers

Comment: I need that content is 100% :)

Comment: Ok just say textarea{ min-width: 100%;} it should be fine like that. Since min-width makes sure the selected element doesn't shrink beyond the specified value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

- Message and *br* element must be removed first. *br* element do not let you to achieve the effect.
- Then you have remove padding from header container (*div*). Padding just overlap your content element with *textarea*.
- Content element with *textarea* element must have fixed height. Otherwise text area will not fill content *div*.
- Then apply for *textarea* element height 100%. That mean that *textarea* will fill whole height of it's parent element.
- Then you can just play with code and do experiments.
  I hope I helped you a little.

Comment: "Content element with textarea element must have fixed height. Otherwise text area will not fill content div."
So How can I get it?

Comment: Just find parent element of textarea and set height to fixed value.

Comment: How? Javascript?

Comment: No. Just apply style _height: some_value;_ to parent element. You can use Javascript to traverse elements, but it is too much for that. Remember fixed value not %.

Comment: But the point is that I can't fix a height value. I need to fill the whole vertical space with textarea. If I set a height to the div content, textarea will have same height, what is the different to set the value directly to it?

Comment: Example: parent height is 100px so if textarea height 100% and its parent height is 100px then textarea height will be also 100px. Also parent height can be 100%, but that parent parent must be fixed value. And so on. Screen is last parent and has fixed height. Height in % requires parent element be fixed value or browser can't calculate height in %. It is like proportion.

Comment: I knew that, for this reason I was looking for a solution where parent wasn't fixed.